# How to add a geometry to an existing feature that was created with NULL geometry?

Tags: qgis, spatialite, null-geometry

I have a simple SpatiaLite geodb loaded in QGIS with one table. There is a POINT geometry field and some alphanumeric data. In some cases I can record data about a specific site, but the coordinates are not available at this time and will be retrieved and recorded later. In some other cases I have the coordinates and I want to insert them right into the geometry field, preferably by clicking on the map canvas in the same way available for adding new features (having a separate text field for the coordinates and generating the geometry from that is a no-go).

How do I add a geometry to an existing feature that was created with a NULL geometry field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this straight in spatialite. Run an UPDATE query each time you have the coordinates available like:

```
UPDATE point_table 
SET geometry=MakePoint(<your_new_x_coord>,<your_new_y_coord>, SRID)   
WHERE site_id=...;
```

This can be done from the spatialite_gui, or one of the QGIS database plugins.
Does that help?

Comment: I should have explained that I need a GUI solution (e.g. click on a map) but maybe that can be done in one of the QGIS plugins?

Comment: How ar eyou adding points to the table with a NULL geometry? I don't think that's possible in QGIS. On the other hand, you could implement a simple trigger to update the geometry column with the actual geometry whenever real x-y coordinates are added.

Comment: It is possible in some cases. See this [other question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43530/how-to-create-add-features-without-geometry/43531) that I posted right now.

Answer (score 20):

If you're after a GUI solution, you can use the "Add Part" tool (QGIS >=2.2 only). First, make your layer editable. Then in an Attribute Table select a single row with a null geometry that you want to add a geometry to. Back in the map canvas, select the "Add Part" tool and draw your geometry. The null geometry will be replaced by your newly drawn shape.

Comment: In QGis 3.0.2, this tool is in **Edit Menu**.

Comment: In 2.18 I had to make the tool visible by going to View > Toolbars > Advanced Digitizing Toolbar