# How to create/add features without geometry?

Tags: qgis

I have a simple SpatiaLite geodb loaded in QGIS with one table. There is a POINT geometry field and some alphanumeric fields.

In some cases I can record data about a specific site, but the coordinates are not available at this time and will be retrieved and recorded later.

How do I add features to this layer without adding their geometries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If the database schema allows so**, you can add geometry-less features in QGIS if the layer can be added as a non-geometric layer: SpatiaLite and PostGIS support this functionality if you enable the "show tables without geometry" option in their respective dialogs. Among the "tables without geometry" there will be also a "duplicate" (so to say) of the tables with a geometry field.

[image: Adding the same table as spatial and non-spatial layer]

You can add both items for a single table and get two layers for one table.

The non-spatial layer will allow you to add new features (via the `+` button in the attributes table) where the `geom` field can be NULL (I repeat, if the database schema allows so):

[image: Adding a new feature with a NULL geometry]

Shapefiles don't allow this kind of work-flow as far as I know. It may not be orthodox, but it works and it can be useful in certain cases.

Comment: I can't see the same layer with and without geometry in QGIS 2.8.1. Anyone can confirm this issue?