# Joining vector layer with CSV-file that contain duplicates in QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv, attribute-joins, import, duplicates

I'm currently working on a project, and I received a CSV file which has additional information about each feature. I intend to join the CSV file with an existing layer. Picture it like this:

[image]

However, as in the picture above, the field I intend to join has some duplicates. This means that not all information will be transferred during the join if I don't edit it beforehand.

It would be helpful if I could get the data to look like this:

[image]

Sometimes when I join different layers, this happens automatically even though I don't want it to. However, since the layer does not have a geometry, I can't use it.

The "Aggregate" tool (and similar) is not really helpful, since I need the fields to remain separate instead of simply put together.

I could create a dummy geometry for each feature. However, in the actual project, I'm working with hundreds of different features and this would take me a longer time than editing it manually. Editing it manually is also not really optimal, as there will be many more features added to the project.

TL;DR: Is there any tool on QGIS that can help me achieve what I need?

Comment: I have, actually! But maybe I don't have the proper vocabulary to find what I was looking for.

Comment: This is data from a single CSV file, like I said initially. There is no geometry, just the dataset. The `fid` does not have to match, as I'm trying to join them by the attribute `name`.

Comment: Not the one from the project, as it contains sensitive data. The dummy dataset I used for the pictures can be recreated quite easily though. I just need the additional data from the duplicates to go into their own column.

Comment: I think Python would be good enough. I was trying to aggregate the values and then split it into different columns, but it is beyong my abilities.

Answer (score 2):

### Python + PyQGIS solution

For now, it is hard to say which fields from the CSV-file you are joining to your original vector data. However, my assumption will be the join is done via the `"name"` attribute, isn't it?

So, let's consider the following example.

There are two objects: a point layer called *'points'* and a CSV-file named *'test'* with some dummy data, see the image below.

[image: input]

The task is the same as yours. I will process the CSV-file, create a temporal layer from this data, and join it to the original vector layer.

Proceed with `Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor` and paste the script below:

```py
# imports
import csv
from os.path import realpath
from itertools import groupby

from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsFeature, QgsVectorLayer, QgsField, QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant

######################################################
### PART 1 : PROCESSING THE ORIGINAL CSV-FILE AND
### PROVIDING THE RESULT STORED AS A LIST WITH DICTS
######################################################

# referring to the original CSV-file
path_to_csv = realpath("D:/qgis_test/test.csv")
# referring to the grouping and working fields in the CSV-file
grouping_field = "city"
working_field = "month"

# opening the csv-file
with open(path_to_csv, 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    # creating a csv reader object
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    # getting original column names
    columns = next(csv_reader) # e.g. 'id', 'city', 'month'
    # getting index of the grouping and working fields
    ind_group = columns.index(grouping_field)
    ind_work = columns.index(working_field)
    
    # getting original data as a list with lists
    original_data = list(csv_reader)
    # grouping data by the second column i.e. "city"
    data_grouped = {key: list(group) for key, group in groupby(original_data, lambda column: column[ind_group])}

    # finding the longest grouped list of data
    n = max(list(len(set(column[ind_work] for column in value)) for value in data_grouped.values()))
    # creating new columns
    new_columns = [columns[ind_work]] + [columns[ind_work] + str(i + 1) for i in range(n) if i > 0]  # 'month', 'month2', 'month3'

    # initiating a temporal storage for processed data
    new_data = []

    # looping over grouped data
    for key, value in data_grouped.items():
        # making storage for processed data
        feature_new_data = {}
        # processing new data for each record
        feature_new_data[grouping_field] = key
        dummy_fill = [None] * n
        #print(value)
        unique_values = set(x[ind_work] for x in value)
        new_values = list(unique_values)[:n] + dummy_fill[len(unique_values):]
        # works for Python >= 3.9 https://peps.python.org/pep-0584/
        feature_new_data = feature_new_data | dict(zip(new_columns, new_values))
        new_data.append(feature_new_data)

######################################################
### PART 2 : CREATING A TEMPORAL LAYER WITH ATTRIBUTE
### TABLE WHERE THE PROCESSED DATA WILL BE STORED
######################################################

# creating the temporal layer
attr_layer = QgsVectorLayer("None", "attr_layer", "memory")
# accessing its provider
provider = attr_layer.dataProvider()

attr_layer.startEditing()

# setting columns that have to be created 
relevant_columns = [columns[ind_group]] + new_columns
# creating columns in the temporal layer
for column in relevant_columns:
    provider.addAttributes([QgsField(column, QVariant.String)])
attr_layer.updateFields()

# nesting new data into the temporal layer
for new_data_set in new_data:
    feat = QgsFeature()
    feat.setAttributes([*new_data_set.values()])
    provider.addFeature(feat)
    attr_layer.updateExtents()

attr_layer.commitChanges()

# If necessary the 'attr_layer' layer can be added to the Project
# QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(attr_layer)

######################################################
### PART 3 : JOINING ORIGINAL VECTOR LAYER WITH
### TEMPORAL THAT CONTAINS PROCESSED DATA
######################################################

# referring to the original Vector layer
point_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("points")[0]

# target layer to join
target_layer_id = attr_layer.id()

# parameters for the join
joining_field = grouping_field
prefix = ""

# Performing join
joinObject = QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo()
joinObject.setJoinFieldName(joining_field)
joinObject.setTargetFieldName(joining_field)
joinObject.setJoinLayerId(target_layer_id)
joinObject.setJoinFieldNamesSubset(new_columns)
joinObject.setPrefix(prefix)
joinObject.setUsingMemoryCache(True)
joinObject.setJoinLayer(attr_layer)

point_layer.addJoin(joinObject)
```

Change the names of the input elements. Press `Run script` [image: run script] and get the output that will look like this:

[image: output]

*Note:* Sorting was not a part of this script.

---

**References:**

- [Reading column names alone in a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836781/reading-column-names-alone-in-a-csv-file)
- [Fill lists in list with zeros if their length less than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70406616/fill-lists-in-list-with-zeros-if-their-length-less-than)
- [Getting dictionary for each feature with their attribute values using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374229/getting-dictionary-for-each-feature-with-their-attribute-values-using-pyqgis)
- [Creating geometry less memory layer using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183692/geometry-less-memory-layer-in-qgis)
- [Creating new empty vector layer with PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30261/creating-new-empty-vector-layer-with-pyqgis)
- [Joining layers with PyQGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267732/joining-layers-with-pyqgis-3)

Answer (score 1):

You **can** use in fact [`Aggregate`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisaggregate) for that and create different new fields during this process.

Simply aggregate all responsibles for each name in an array an then get the first element of the array (index 0: `[0]`) for `responsible1`, the 2nd element for `responsible2` etc. In the Aggregate dialog, replace the Field name in `Source Expression` with this expression:

```
array_agg (responsible,group_by:=name)[0]
```

Then add additonal fields an proceed accordingly.

[image]

---

If you have a large dataset and you do not know how many new fields you have to create (maximum number of responsibles for the same city/name), you can calculate this number in the field calculator with this expression:

```
case 
when    $id = minimum ($id)
then    maximum( 
            array_length(
                array_filter ( 
                    array_agg ("responsible", group_by:="name"), 
                    @element is not NULL
                )
            )
        )
end
```

*In this case, you have to create 4 new fields as Schwerin appears 5 times, but only 4 times with a responsible; all other names appear less then 4 times:*

[image]